# Read through a stream reader and use some text from line

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, stream, inputstream

Using a streamReader to read through a file.
If the line starts with `1`, i want to use this line.
The line will read something like: `1,103,1,4454:HH`

So I want to grab the number after the first `,` but before the second. So i need `103` and assign it to ProductId:

```
int ProductID;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fakeFileToProcess))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        if (line.StartsWith("1,"))
        {
            //so line will be 1,103,1,44543:HH
            //How do I capture the '103'...something like:
            //ProductID = line.read between "1," & ","(next comma)

        }

        if (line.StartsWith("25"))
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to achieve this:

From MSDN : **String.Split()**

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string array. A
>   parameter specifies whether to return empty array elements.

Try This:

```
string num = line.Split(',')[1].Trim();
if(int.TryParse(str,out ProductID)
{
   //success now ProductID contains int value (103)
}
```

**Complete Code:**

```
int ProductID;    
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fakeFileToProcess))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        if (line.StartsWith("1,"))
        {
            string num = line.Split(',')[1].Trim();
            if(int.TryParse(str,out ProductID)
            {
                //parsing is successful, now ProductID contains int value (103)
            }    
        }

        if (line.StartsWith("25"))
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you have a so clear delimited data.
`IndexOf` is better  than splitting a string in its parts because you don't need to create an array of strings

```
   if (line.StartsWith("1,"))
   {
       // search the second comma after  the first one....
       int pos = line.IndexOf(',', 2);

       // for simplicity, do not check if you really have found a second comma....
       string id = line.Substring(2, pos - 2);

       // Try to convert whatever is between the first comma and the second one..
       if(Int32.TryParse(id, out productID))
           Console.WriteLine("Got it:" + productID.ToString());

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string.Split()` method to acheive what you want.
To convert to an `int` use the `int.Parse()` method.

So you can do the following:

```
List<string> items = line.Split(',');
ProductID = int.Parse(items[1]);
```